# Wrapping a QStringListModel in a QAbstractItemModel renders a blank list

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to start off making my own models for Qt list views, and I thought that I would start by wrapping a `QStringListModel` in my own `QAbstractItemModel`, then render it in a list view.  However, it only renders a blank white square, instead of the list I expect.  I don't really know what could be happening, given that all I'm doing is delegating all calls to the `QStringListModel`.  Perhaps there's some aspects of the `QStringListModel` that are called by the `QListView` that are not mandated by the `QAbstractItemModel` pure virtual methods?  Or maybe it's related to storage of the `QStringList` somehow?

My attempt is below.  The header:

```
class DelegatingItemModel: public QAbstractItemModel {
public:
    DelegatingItemModel();

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

private:
    QAbstractItemModel* innerModel;
};
```

This is the implementation:

```
#include "delegating_item_model.hh"

DelegatingItemModel::DelegatingItemModel() {
    QStringList available = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
    this->innerModel = new QStringListModel(available);
}

QVariant DelegatingItemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    return innerModel->data(index, role);
}

int DelegatingItemModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return innerModel->columnCount(parent);
}

int DelegatingItemModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return innerModel->rowCount(parent);
}

QModelIndex DelegatingItemModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const {
    return innerModel->parent(index);
}

QModelIndex DelegatingItemModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    return innerModel->index(row, column, parent);
}
```

And this is the entry point:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    qDebug() << "Starting up";
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mainWindow;

    QListView* listView = new QListView;
    DelegatingItemModel* theModel = new DelegatingItemModel;

    listView->setModel(theModel);

    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(listView);
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: _"I don't really know what could be happening, given that all I'm doing is delegating all calls to the QStringListModel"_ then why not using it directly ?

Comment: @Scab eventually I want to make more complicated model classes, but I wanted to try a simple example to understand how they work first.

Comment: Then `QAbstractListModel` could also be an interesting intermediate step if you need a more generic but still one-dimensional list model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view will get data from the model only if the given index is linked to its model. If you print a trace in the data() method, you will see that it's never called.

So, you cannot return a new index created by your inner list model because it will be linked to the list and not your own model. For example:

```
QModelIndex DelegatingItemModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const {
    //return innerModel->index(row, column, parent);
    if (parent.isValid()) // It's a list. Not a tree
        return QModelIndex();
    return createIndex(row, column); // Create a index for your own model.
}
```

To be full compliant, you should convert the index in data():

```
QVariant DelegatingItemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    QModelIndex const innerIndex(innerModel->index(index.row(), index.column()));
    return innerModel->data(innerIndex, role);
}
```

Comment: This works, great!  I'll read up more about how the `QModelIndex` works.